# php-cgi.exe - does it detect and handle both CGI and FastCGI? If so, how?

Tags: php, cgi, fastcgi

The impression I get both from Microsoft's discussions about [FastCGI and PHP](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/248/configuring-fastcgi-extension-for-iis-60/), and also from [Coast R&D's site](http://www.coastrd.com/iis-web-server), is that php-cgi.exe is able to detect whether it is being used in either a CGI or FastCGI context. If so, how does it do it, as I'd like to have similar functionality in my own product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not look at the PHP source code? As long as you don't copy their code line for line, there's no risk of IP issues.

Comment: D'oh! (blush) should've thought o' that, it being open source 'n' all.